# DynamoDBStreams GetRecords with --limit returns empty records

Tags: amazon-web-services, limit, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm trying to run DynamoDBStreams GetRecords command with `--limit` option but nothing is returned...

```sh
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.266 Python/3.5.2 Linux/5.3.0-28-generic botocore/1.13.2


$ aws dynamodbstreams --profile my-profile --region my-region get-records --shard-iterator my-shard-iterator --limit 2
# Output
{
    "NextShardIterator": "my-next-shard-iterator",
    "Records": []
}
```

When I remove the `--limit` option, Some records are returned:

```sh
$ aws dynamodbstreams --profile my-profile --region my-region get-records --shard-iterator my-shard-iterator
# Output
{
    "Records": [
          {
             # record 1
          },
          {
             # record 2
          }
     ],
    "NextShardIterator": "my-next-shard-iterator"
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodbstreams/get-records.html#options)

> --limit (integer)
>   The maximum number of records to return from the shard. The upper limit is 1000.

Am I doing something wrong or this option does not work globally ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the first case include the `NextShardIterator`? If so, my guess would be that you need to call it again, with that value set to `--shard-iterator`. If this works anything like filtering on scans/queries, you can get no results and it doesn't mean there aren't any results to get. If `NextShartIterator` is null, then you're at the end.

Comment: In the two cases, I use the same shard iterator. When the --limit is defined, nothing is returned. But without this option I have records...

Comment: When you say "nothing is returned" you mean no records, but does the object returned include a `NextShardIterator`?

Comment: Yes I mean no records. Indeed, I have the `NextShardIterator` key. But I loop thought the next shard iterator indefinitely with no records...

Comment: Indefinitely? Hmmm. Does the one without limits return the same value for `NextShardIterator` as the one with limits?

Comment: Nice catch. It seems that the NextShardIterator are indeed difference between the two commands.

Comment: When I run a lot (16) of aws get-records commands conccurently it seems that data are returned with `--limit` option. But I don't understand how limit works. Can you lighten me please ?

Comment: The `--limit x` option is saying never give me more than `x` records at a time. I'm assuming that when you ask for records it's acting like a scan operation with a filter. You may get no results but need to keep calling to get to the next record. When you don't set the limit the call is grabbing enough records to not hit that. It's entirely possible that, with enough (or big enough) records in the stream, the call without the limit might not return any data. Never rely on the record count to indicate you are done, always rely on the `NextShardIterator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--limit` seems to work. But it is a little long to retrieve records from the correct shard iterator.

Comment: What do you mean by a little long? When do I decide to stop the iteration, I can't simply keep on hitting the API indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same that is happening to me.

I get 0 records in the API response with the next shard iterator. I try this shard iterator again and ask for the records. It may or may not responds with the records. Sometimes I have to do this 500 times to get a single record. What I want to understand is how many times do we need to do this to completely read the data from the shard.

From [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_GetRecords.html):

> Specify a shard iterator using the ShardIterator parameter. The shard iterator specifies the position in the shard from which you want to start reading stream records sequentially. If there are no stream records available in the portion of the shard that the iterator points to, GetRecords returns an empty list. **Note that it might take multiple calls to get to a portion of the shard that contains stream records.**

Check the note in bold from the above statements. What does it means?

Comment: did you get an answer to what  **Note that it might take multiple calls to get to a portion of the shard that contains stream records.** means? I tried skipping the shard when I hit the shard 10 times and got back empty records. I started noticing I was missing records. I increased it to 100 times and the missing records were then processed. 10, 100 are so arbitrary.